# Squid проксирование OPTIONS запросов

Tags: linux, proxy, squid

Не могу понять, почему squid не проксирует запросы с методом `OPTIONS`. Кто-то уже с этим сталкивался?

```
Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Squid 3.5.12
```

В логах это выглядит таким образом

```
1524045224.861      0 178.46.109.103 TAG_NONE/503 0 CONNECT ipv6-internet.yandex.net:443 root HIER_NONE/- -
```

При установке опции `extension_methods OPTIONS` получаю ошибку

```
2018/04/18 09:42:33| ERROR: Directive 'extension_methods' is obsolete.
```

Подскажите, как настроить проктирование запросов с методом `OPTIONS` и возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: ну во-первых, `Directive 'extension_methods' is obsolete` - последний раз использовалась в версии 3.0; а во-вторых, вызывает подозрение хост `ipv6-internet.yandex.net` - не резолвится он...

Comment: Это я для примера показал. На самом деле, когда заходишь на [Яндекс.Интернетометр](https://yandex.ru/internet/), там есть кнопка "Измерить" состояние интернета. Так вот в процессе измерения именно "Исходящего соединения", отправляется запрос на адрес "https://cache-man-default03i.cdn.yandex.net/upload?1524053631560" с методом OPTIONS. Этот запрос обрывает мой сервер и по этому измерить скорость не получается

Comment: хм... замерил, сидя за сквидом - всё ок. Не знаю, что вам предложить.

Comment: Можете предложить конфиг своего сервера :) Буду крайне признателен. И ещё хотелось бы уточнить версию вашего сервера

Comment: Версия 3.5.20. Конфиг постить сюда бесполезно - не влезет, и смысла нет - он у меня "тупой" до безобразия - одни acl-и, и ничего, чтобы относилось к конфигурации протокола. Т.е. конфиг можно сказать дефолтный, расширенный слегка моими внутренними потребностями запретов хождения по разным сайтам. Кстати, откуда вы узнали, что нечто отправляется методом OPTIONS и из-за него происходит `падение`? tcpdump-ом смотрели?

Comment: Нет, просто в браузере консоль открыл и увидел там какой запрос падает. Потом грепнул по этому хосту /var/log/squid/access.log и увидел строку с тем же `TAG_NONE/503`. Подскажите ещё: вы его в `transparent` режиме используете? Наистраивали ли вы пулы для ограничения скорости? Включена ли авторизаци и какая, если не секрет? И включена ли опция `dns_v4_first`?

Comment: Ну 503, это насколько я помню - Service Unavailable, т.е. это скорее не проблема прокси. Все же 500-е ошибки - это ответы сервера. Нет, не транспарент. Обычный http-прокси на порту 3128. Пулов никаких нет. Аутентификация kerberos, авторизация - LDAP. Опцию `dns_v4_first` не определял.

Comment: Вряд ли у яндекса "service unavailable". При этом без прокси тесты проходят. Ладно, если решу эту проблему, то отпишусь тут потом...